# Set the time for html local storage

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I have this html local storage, that saves a cookie, but I want that if the browser restarts this cookie dont be available again, so if the user visits the site it will show the popup again

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
        $("#popup").delay(2000).fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    }

    $('#popup-close').click(function(e) // You are clicking the close button
    {
    $('#popup').fadeOut(); // Now the pop up is hiden.
    });

});
```

I dont know how to set a life time for this, like 10 min or something

Comment: you can use `beforeunload` event which will be triggered on tab reload/close, something like: window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { localStorage.removeItem('popState') });. Is it cover your case?

Comment: so instead of storing a boolean, store the timestamp and check the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` does not have any expiry time. But you can implement your own logic while reading/writing to `localStorage`.

For example, along with the actual data you can store the expiry time as well and while reading check if the time is past the expiry time then consider the value unavailable.

Example code (from [here](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript-localstorage-with-ttl-expiry/)) -

```
function setLocalStorageItemWithExpiry(key, value, expiryTimeInMs) {
    const now = new Date()

    // `item` is an object which contains the original value
    // as well as the time when it's supposed to expire
    const item = {
        value: value,
        expiry: now.getTime() + expiryTimeInMs,
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item))
}

function getLocalStorageItemWithExpiry(key) {
    const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
    // if the item doesn't exist, return null
    if (!itemStr) {
        return null
    }
    const item = JSON.parse(itemStr)
    const now = new Date()
    // compare the expiry time of the item with the current time
    if (now.getTime() > item.expiry) {
        // If the item is expired, delete the item from storage
        // and return null
        localStorage.removeItem(key)
        return null
    }
    return item.value
}
```

Usage -

```
const value = getLocalStorageItemWithExpiry('myKey');
if (!value) {
    // Your logic
    setLocalStorageItemWithExpiry('myKey', 'testvalue', 60000); // 60000 ms = 1 min
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with that and some chances I could do what I want!